# How to eliminate duplicate code for server-side cleanup when using UpdateModel()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm a bit confused as to the correct way to save changes to my edit model object in ASP.NET MVC 3 using EF4, especially when I want to do some server-side clean-up just before saving. My action method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EmployeeEditModel employeeEditModel) {
  var originalEmployee = db.Employees.Single(c => c.Id == id);

  // if I don't do this here, I can't check for complex model errors that follows
  employeeEditModel.Employee.LastHireDate = employeeEditModel.Employee.LastHireDate.Date;
  employeeEditModel.Employee.EmployeeNumber = employeeEditModel.Employee.EmployeeNumber.ToUpper();

  if (employeeEditModel.Employee.LastHireDate < employeeEditModel.Employee.OriginalHireDate) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Employee.LastHireDate", "Last Hire Date cannot occur before Original Hire Date.");
  }

  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    UpdateModel(originalEmployee, "Employee");
    // if I don't do this here, these changes won't be saved
    originalEmployee.LastHireDate = originalEmployee.LastHireDate.Date;
    originalEmployee.EmployeeNumber = originalEmployee.EmployeeNumber.ToUpper();

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(getEmployeeEditModel(id));
}
```

You can see I want to clean up a couple items such as dropping off the time portion in a `DateTime` field, converting another to uppercase, and trimming whitespace off another (not shown). This is a representative sample of some fields that I can sanitize for which I ought not need to bother the user.
The problem is I seem to have to do this twice in the code I've found myself in (refer to the comments in the code). I'm updating an edit model that contains a handful of objects that are stored logically in separate tables.

This code works, but isn't how I know it should be. Should I be using `UpdateModel()` or something else in this situation? How can I avoid repeating myself in cleaning up both objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. Start with `UpdateModel` and do your cleanup only on the EF object. If you have model errors, just don't commit before leaving the action.
2. Instead of using `UpdateModel` use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for updating your EF model object with teh cleaned values of your ViewModel object.

Comment: For #1, am I asking for trouble if I try updating the model before doing my other checks (before checking that `ModelState.IsValid`)?

Comment: What kind of trouble are you afraid of? ´UpdateModel()´ just sets some properties on your model. As long as you don't call ´SubmitChanges()´ the changed values are discarded when you leave the action method.

Comment: Digging a little more, I realize my 'clean-up' belongs elsewhere (model binders for a start). I suppose there isn't any reason why I couldn't `TryModelUpdate()` near the start of the method. I just got the impression by seeing other examples that it should come immediately before saving.